# casperjs unable to open file

Tags: terminal, casperjs

This may be a simple question but I can't for the life of me figure out what I'm doing wrong. I'm experimenting with casperjs to build a scraper. I've followed the tutorial for downloading it with brew found here:

```
http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/installation.html
```

I then continued onto the quick start found here:

```
http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html
```

I saved the sample.js file to my desktop and attempted to run it from terminal using:

```
$ casperjs sample.js
```

However it always returns unable to open file: sample.js. If I just run $ casperjs in the terminal all of the information about what version it is etc comes up so it seems like casperjs is installed correctly.

I also made sure the required prerequisites were installed. I realize this isn't a whole lot of information to go on but does anyone have any ideas?

This is the error code I get in the terminal:

```
Unable to open file: sample.js
```

Second edit:

Maybe where I'm having trouble is with these prerequisites?

```
Python 2.6 or greater for casperjs in the bin/ directory
```

I have python installed but I'm not sure about the "for casper in the bin/ directory" part. The documentation doesn't say anything about how to do that.

Comment: I edited to include the error message. Yes, phantomjs and python are both installed.

Answer (score 2):

Phantom 1.9.7-15 and Casper 1.0.3

In my case, while typed 'casper testScript.js' this was going to node_module/.../.../casper and was trying to find the file testScript.js which was in different place. Changing the name of file to full path fixed the issue.
Also i think that message displayed is a little bit incorrect, "Unable to open file:" isn't "file not found" ...

Quick fix: change the 'testScript.js' part for  full path.
For me, helped.
From:

```
Unable to open file: testScript.js
```

To:

```
CasperJS, a navigation scripting and testing utility for PhantomJS and SlimerJS 
PhantomJS | PhantomJS
```

Later I've changed the  PATH variables and aliases. Everything works fine.

Hope it will help someone.